# The correct usage of 'Not only' in the beginning of a negative sentence

Tags: grammaticality, grammar

Am I  using *Not only . . . but also* correctly?

1. Not only have these conditions been not prepared in developed countries, but developing countries also have not accepted them.
2. Not only have not these conditions been prepared in developed countries, but also have developing countries not accepted them.
3. Not only have these conditions not been prepared in developed countries, but (also) in developing countries.

Could you tell me which sentence is correct, where the right location of *not* in the above examples is, and whether  we can ignore the verb after *but also* like example 3?

In the end, do you have any better idea for writing the mentioned example less casually?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Regarding your primary question of the position of 'not' following a sentence that starts with 'Not only..', the third option seems correct. Because, the verb to be negated is 'been prepared' and therefore, the position of 'not' would be right before it.

But I have my doubts whether the 'Not only..but also' sentence structure is the right choice to convey the meaning you wish to convey.

Something like...

> These conditions have neither been prepared in developed countries, nor been accepted in developing countries

...feels much less complex, but conveys pretty much the same meaning as far as I understand

**Edit :** And as @nonchip said, omitting the 'also' doesn't seem to be  good idea.

Comment: Thanks, but I want to know what is the exact difference between: Not only ('have these conditions not been prepared', 'have not these conditions been prepared' and 'have these conditions been not prepared') in developed....

Comment: @A.Gh, This is probably one situation where 'correctness' is pretty much subjective and depends on what feels right. Though there's nothing wrong per se with the position of 'not' in the other two options, the third option simply follows the convention and puts the 'not' in a position that causes no confusion. It also seems to give a flow to the sentence because it is immediately followed by the verb form 'been prepared' :)

Playing around with sentence structure is widely used in literature, though.

Answer (score 2):

the third sentence is correct, but I'd avoid omitting the "also". ignoring the verb eliminates information, because the developing countries are not refusing to prepare, but accept them.

Comment: Please write answers in standard English format - this ***is*** an "English language & usage" site! Also, please explain why #3 is 'correct' and the others are wrong, so as to help the OP and other users apply the information to other scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

Sentence (3) seems to have a different intended meaning from (1) and (2).

There is a complication in changing from a passive to an active construction when moving from the 'not only' to the 'but also' strings.

Sachin's rewrite is vastly better.

Answer (score 1):

I find sentences 1 & 2 awkward (at best) because of the positioning of "not":

> 1. Not only have these conditions *been not prepared* in developed countries, but developing countries also have not accepted them.
> 2. Not only have *not these conditions been prepared* in developed countries, but also have developing countries not accepted them.

As @EdwinAshworth has commented, sentence 3 has a different meaning because the other two sentences refer to *acceptance* by developing countries, whereas the last sentence refers (implicitly) to *preparation* by developing countries:

> 3- Not only have these conditions not been *prepared* in developed countries, but *(also) in developing countries*.

Although I'm not 100% certain what you're trying to say, my suggestion of rewording while retaining your words as closely as possible, would be to adopt the first part of your sentence 3, with a modified version of the last part of your sentence 1:

> Not only have these conditions not been prepared in developed countries, but *neither* have developing countries *accepted them*.
>   Not only have these conditions not been prepared in developed countries, but *neither have they been accepted by* developing countries.

Of those, I prefer the latter because the second part more closely reflects the first part:

> Not only have these ***conditions not been*** prepared in developed countries, but neither have [the ***conditions] been*** accepted by developing countries.

Answer (score 0):

I would argue all of these are wrong. They never establish a subject, but it is implied. Not only... is an adverbial clause followed by a conjunction with a predicate.